# Can I make a php file become a package or library?

Tags: php

I have a utility.php file, but I would like to build it become a library, or something else, just don't want people can't access the utility.php directly, but they can access it via other page, for example, a register.php, can use the utility.php, how can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php //utility.php
    if(!defined('UTILITY_INCLUDED'){
         die('Grrrr...');
    }
?>
```

and then like this:

```
<?php //yourFile.PHP
    define('UTILITY_INCLUDED', TRUE);
    include ("utility.php";
?>
```

You have many other options to protect `utility.php`

- Put it some other directory, and prevent access through .htaccess file
- Use `count(`[get_included_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php)`)==1`.. etc

Comment: should I put all the source code in other directory.... ....only use the "include" to include the source code to prevent other get access to the source code?

Comment: Yes, make sure that the contents of the directory isnt accessible through htaccess file. Or rather, put the utility.php file above the www/public_html/whatever; no need for htaccess then.

Answer (score 0):

You could include utility.php into any other PHP file. For example:

```
 //Register.php

 include('utility.php');

 //Use any functions from the utility.php file
 utility_function();
```